# Outlier treatment of large dataset

Tags: r, outliers

I am doing a project and have a dataset of 8545 X 52.
Every variable has outlier in it and unfortunately I can't remove the outliers.
I know the method of capping by checking for IQR of each column but as number of columns is 52 it will take a lot of time.
Can anyone suggest any quick method to treat the outliers.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It’s easier to help if you make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). Include the code you have tried and set out your expected answer. These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

A very quick (and dirty) way to check for and identify outliers is this:

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c(sample(1:10, 9), 1000),
  v2 = c(runif(9), 2000),
  v3 = c(11111, rnorm(8), 23450))
```

Boxplots per se identify outliers; they can be retrieved via `$out`:

```
boxplot(df)$out
[1]   100  2000 11111  2345
```

To detect these values in your dataframe, you can use `sapply`:

```
sapply(df, function(x) x %in% boxplot(df)$out)
         v1    v2    v3
 [1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[10,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```